# How to return multple files from ZipInputStream

Tags: java

I'm downloading a zip file from an ftp server. The zip file contains a couple csv files. I'm trying to extract both csv files so that I can pass them into Opencsv, but I seem to be having some issues. I'm assuming there must be a better way to handle this than the way I'm doing it below. How do you return my csv files so that they are available in a list for my csv reader?

My code

```
ftp.retrieveFile(file, output);
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());

Map<String, InputStream> inputStreams = new HashMap<>();

if (importTask.isZipfile()) {
    inputStreams.put("products", importUtils.getZipData(new ZipInputStream(inputStream), importTask.getFilename()));

    if(importTask.getCustomerFilename() != null) {
        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
        inputStreams.put("customers", importUtils.getZipData(new ZipInputStream(inputStream), importTask.getCustomerFilename()));
    }
} else {
    inputStreams.put("products", inputStream);
}

ftp.logout();
ftp.disconnect();

return inputStreams;
```

Zip

```
public InputStream getZipData(ZipInputStream zip, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    for (ZipEntry e; (e = zip.getNextEntry()) != null;) {

        if (e.getName().equals(filename)) {
            return zip;
        }
    }
    throw new FileNotFoundException("zip://" + filename);
}
```

Comment: Which version of Java?

Comment: What is the problem you get with this code?

Comment: I think I just got it to work, it appears my problem was else where, but isn't this inefficient?

Comment: Another issue I experienced was the inputstream became null so I had to get it again from the output.toByteArray() Why whould that happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 7+ you have an easier solution than that; you can just use the zip filesystem provider.

Here is some sample code; note that you need to `.close()` the generated `InputStream`s and `FileSystem`s:

```
public static void getFsFromZipFile(final Path zipFile)
    throws IOException
{
    final URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zipFile.toUri());

    final Map<String, ?> env = Collections.singletonMap("readonly", "true");

    return FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
}

public static getInputStreamFromZip(final FileSystem zipfs, final String name)
    throws IOException
{
    return Files.newInputStream(zipfs.getPath(name));
}
```

This is not how I'd recommend you do it however. What I'd recommend is this:

```
final Map<String, Path> getFilesFromZip(final Path zipFile, final String... names)
    throws IOException
{
    Path tmpfile;

    final URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zipFile.toUri());

    final Map<String, ?> env = Collections.singletonMap("readonly", "true);

    final Map<String, Path> ret = new HashMap<>();

    try (
        final FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
    ) {
        for (final String name: names) {
            tmpfile = Files.createTempFile("tmp", ".csv");
            Files.copy(zipfs.getPath(name), tmpfile);
            ret.put(name, tmpfile);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused as to how I would get the path while retrieving the file as a ByteArrayOutputStream from the ftp server.

Comment: Just save the output stream to a file on disk and use that afterwards